# How do I uninstall ctags on MacOSX?

Tags: macos, unix, vim, ctags

I was messing around with vim, and every now and again my CPU goes to 100% running ctags. It's getting annoying, I can't figure out how to uninstall it. I've tried 'sudo port uninstall ctags' but that didn't do anything. I thought I uninstalled the vim package that was using it but apparently not. How do I uninstall ctags?

Comment: What plugins do you use? TagBar? TagList? Could you post your `.vimrc`? In Terminal.app, what does `$ which ctags` say?

Answer (score 0):

Through Terminal:

```
locate ctags;
```

should output all filenames containing the string 'ctags', in the locate database. If the database has not been built try:

```
/usr/libexec/locate.updatedb;
```

default location of ctags is: /usr/bin/ctags

```
rm /usr/bin/ctags;
```

for deletion.

```
grep -rni ctags ~/.vim/*;
```

and

```
grep -rni ctags /Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/*;
```

will give you all the files and their line numbers that contain the string 'ctags' (case insensitive) and are nested into the subfolders of the designated path respectively. An approach which could help to narrow down the search for the triggering file.